# How do I change this code into something that doesn't repeat again?

Tags: java

So, I am still new to Java and while I've been practicing using BlueJ, I encountered a repetition in my program. I need help understanding this in the most simple way and if possible, suggest ways on how to change this code into a simpler one with explanations :)

```js
import java.util.*;
public class Name //This program has a separate main class
{
    public static String FirstName;
    public static String LastName;
    public static String FullName = FirstName + (" ") + LastName;
    public static String Choice;
    
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void callName(){ }
    public Name () {
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        
        if(userInput.hasNextLine()){
            this.setFirstName(userInput.nextLine());}
             
            System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
            
            if(userInput.hasNextLine()){
                this.setLastName(userInput.nextLine());}
                
                System.out.println("Hello there, " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " :3");
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            System.out.println("\nWould you like to know your:");
            System.out.println("A. BMI");
            System.out.println("B. Grades for Major Subjects");
            System.out.println("If none, Press X to exit.");
        if(userInput.hasNextLine()){
            this.setChoice(userInput.nextLine());}
            if(userInput.hasNextLine()){
                BMI show = new BMI();
                show.sayBMI();
            }
            }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String FirstName){
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return LastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String LastName){
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }
    public String getChoice(){
        return Choice;
    }
    public void setChoice(String Choice){
        this.Choice = Choice;
    }
}
```

And it connects with this other class named BMI, I'm not done with it yet because I paused it after I realized it kept repeating;

```js
import java.util.*;
public class BMI extends Name //Again, this program has a separate MAIN class that executes the entire thing
{
    public void sayBMI(){}
    
    private static int Feet;
    private static int Inch;
    public static double Height;
    public static double Weight;
    
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public BMI()
    {
        System.out.println("So you want to know your BMI, " + FullName + "?");
    }

}
```

When I execute the program, it runs like this:

"Enter your first name: Franz
Enter your last name: Sarmiento
Hello there, Franz Sarmiento :3

Would you like to know your:
A. BMI
B. Grades for Major Subjects
If none, Press X to exit.
A

Enter your first name: Enter your last name: 
Hello there,   :3 "

And I stopped there because it is continuous.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

From having a quick look your problem is arising as you're extending Name from BMI.

```
public class BMI extends Name
```

Inheritance: A class that is derived from another class is called subclass and inherits all fields and methods of its superclass.

Simply remove the extends Name part and your program should stop looping.

```
public class BMI
```

I hope this solves your issue, good luck.

Comment: But sir, I need to use the FullName for the BMI from the user's input in the Name class :/ How do I do that?

Comment: Could you just make a User object- give it a name, BMI etc?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm sorry I'm still really new to this :/